# How do I get mysqli set up for accessing in php7.4 in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

Im setting up a new server on Ubuntu 20.04, and installed the LAMP apps. apache2 works fine and is accessing the PHP modules fine with the exception of getting the MySQLi database connection working. If I do: `php -m` It does say that mysqli is loaded and there, but when restoring my joomla backup it can't get past the point of connecting to the database.

Any help?

Comment: Silly question, but is Joomla using the `root` MySQL account? If so, that needs to change.

Comment: Yes it is. Let me try using a separate user account...

Comment: Was using the mysql root account, which is no longer supported. Using a new user account worked fine...